# AWS RDS instance error: Unable to find main route table - timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm receiving the following error when trying create a new RDS instance.

[image]

I'm new to AWS, what is this error referring to?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No, I wasn't . Maybe there is an issue with AWS.

Comment: if you're in us-east-1, there have been some errors today on the status dashboard: http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when there are issues on the AWS region where you are creating the instance, I was experiencing the exact same issue, then switched to another region an was able to create the instance with no issues.